# Is there a VBA to number different sets of data using autofill

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to number sets of data that are separated by an empty row. I am thinking an autofill VBA would be what I am needing but cannot seem to find anything that fits specifically what I am looking to do. The issue I am running into is that the data will vary and will not always have the same exact number of rows in each sequence. Given that, I would like Column A (Count) to increase according to information being in Column C (Last Name) and start over when there is an empty row until the end of the sheet. I have put an example of what I am looking for as the end result below. Thank You!

```
Count   ID   Last Name First Name           
1   344969  Test    Test
2           Test    Test
3   344971  Test    Test
4           Test    Test
5   344973  Test    Test
6   344974  Test    Test
7   344975  Test    Test
8           Test    Test
(Blank Row)         
1           Test 2  Test 3
2   200474  Test 2  Test 3
3   200475  Test 2  Test 3
4   200476  Test 2  Test 3
5           Test 2  Test 3
6   200478  Test 2  Test 3
7   200479  Test 2  Test 3
8           Test 2  Test 3
9           Test 2  Test 3
10  200482  Test 2  Test 3
(Blank Row)         
1   195959  Test 5  Test 6
2   195960  Test 5  Test 6
3   195961  Test 5  Test 6
4   195962  Test 5  Test 6
5   195963  Test 5  Test 6
6   195964  Test 5  Test 6
7   195965  Test 5  Test 6
8   195966  Test 5  Test 6
9   195967  Test 5  Test 6
10  195968  Test 5  Test 6
```

I have tried conditional formatting with no luck. I have several other macros in place and would like to add one that performs this function.

Comment: You could do this with a formula. Is there any reason you need VBA?

Comment: The data I will be using will be different every time. I have macros setup to perform other functions in organizing the spreadsheet as well. The individual I am creating this template for does not know excel at all so it would be easier for them to press a button and it be done automatically. I think it is more for consistency that I am wanting VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```vb
Sub countSomething()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet name")
Dim lrow As Long: lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row at the column that will always be populated
Dim R As Long, X As Long: X = 1


For R = 2 To lrow
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells(R, 1).Resize(1, 4)) = 0 Then 'empty row
        X = 1
    Else
        ws.Cells(R, 1) = X
        X = X + 1
    End If
Next R

End Sub
```